# Poor performance of WPF application reading from Excel on separate thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, performance, excel

I have some code in my project that reads from and writes into Excel 2003 using Excel COM API. Now this piece of code is called from two places:
1. From within the Excel add-in itself, on the same thread.
2. From a WPF application, where the WPF window was invoked on a separate thread.

The issue is, when the WPF application invokes the code, the normal operation of reading from Excel that should take 10 seconds is taking 2 minutes. I think it is because of the invocation from a new thread, but I'm not 100% sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: I take it the 10 second target is based on the code running inside Excel?  The WPF COM call will likely have to start the Excel process.  Have you tried it with the process already running?

Comment: You're right. The 10-second target is based on code inside Excel. But even via WPF, the Excel is always open, and the code is invoked on that instance. Excel COM API works off the active instance, in that we don't need to provide the name of the Excel file anywhere.

Comment: The only thing I could possibly suggest then is that there is chattiness between the two processes.  All data will need to be marshalled across the process boundaries, and marshalled from managed to unmanaged.  Chattiness will exacerbate this.  If it isn't chatty, then I'm not sure where the performance problems lie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of things to consider:

- The COM API likely launches the Excel process.  It takes time to start the process and wait for it to be ready.
- There is likely a process boundary being crossed, this is slower than in-proc stuff.
- You may have fallen into the trap of thread-affinity of the COM objects you create in code.  They might have affinity with the thread they were created on, meaning even though you use a COM object on another thread, the actual running of that code is marshalled back to the owning thread of the object.  This should be obvious, however, as your UI will stutter if the code is intensive enough.

Sorry this isn't a direct answer, but it gives some points to explore.

Comment: Managed to improve performance by a considerable bit (now any operation takes 10-12 seconds). Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @Prakash did you determine the exact problem in the end?  Was it one of the points I mentioned?

Comment: The problem was with the communication between the separate threads. I made a change to pass the current thread's Dispatcher so that all messages are handled by that Dispatcher instead. That did the trick.

Comment: Nice one, I'll remember that in future as well - didn't consider the dispatcher.